# Multiple Visual Studio (2012) profiles (addons + settings)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I use Visual Studio 2012 for both C# and C++ development. I also use different extensions depending on the current working project: ReSharper for C# and Visual Assist X for C++.

Is there a way of creating multiple Visual Studio profiles (or installations of the same version) that will use a specific (and different) set of extensions? Currently I have to deactivate/reactivate some manually and it's getting annoying that such a feature doesn't exist (at least something like Eclipse's workspace)

Combine this with different environment setting (e.g.: tabs and spaces settings) for each project and you'll soon get mad. I know we can use different settings files, but it's still annoying to have to re-import a specific .vssettings file each time you open a different project.

Thanks.

Comment: Resharper/VAssistX seem to play well together if you exclude all C# file types from VAssistX?

Comment: Hmm. I've added '.cs' to excluded VAssistX files and it seems it won't trample on ReSharper anymore. Though I wanted a totally separate profile, because VAssistX and ReSharper are just two of the different extensions I use for C++ and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered "Run As" for Visual Studio and use another Windows User Account?  That should allow you to disable R# and VisualAssist separately.

There used to be a way to run a Macro to import an exported settings file, but they removed the Macro functionality in VS2012 (sadly).  You could write an extension that manages importing different settings I guess.